# Proof in Grassman algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V= \mathbb R^{2n}$ and $\alpha$ a bilinear anti-symmetric form, $\alpha \in \Lambda^2V^{\star}$ If we assume that $\alpha^n \in \Lambda^{2n}V^{\star}$ is non zero, is $\alpha$ a symplectic 2-form (ie non degenerate)?

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector $v \in V$, you can define an operation $\iota_v \colon \Lambda^{j} V^{*} \rightarrow \Lambda^{j-1} V^{*}$ by the formula

$$ \iota_v(\alpha)(v_1, \dots, v_{j-1}) = \alpha(v,v_1,\dots,v_{j-1}). $$

This operation is called the interior product and defines a derivation of degree $-1$ on $\oplus_{j=0}^{\dim V} \Lambda^j(V^{*})$. Thus, it satisfies the Liebnitz rule

$$ \iota_v(\beta \wedge \gamma) = \iota_v(\beta) \wedge \gamma \pm \beta \wedge \iota_v(\gamma) $$

for all $\beta \in \Lambda^j(V^{*}), \gamma \in \Lambda^k(V^{*})$ and $0 \leq j, k \leq 2n$ (where the sign of the second factor won't be important for our purposes).

Now, assume that $\alpha$ is degenerate. Thus, we can find $0 \neq v \in V$ such that $\alpha(v,w) = 0$ for all $w \in V$. In other words, $\iota_v(\alpha) = 0$. By repeated application of the Liebnitz rule, we also have $\iota_v(\alpha^k) = 0$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$ and in particular, $\iota_v(\alpha^n) = 0$. Let's complete $v$ to a basis $v = e_1, \dots, e_{2n}$ of $V$. Then

$$ \iota_v(\alpha^n)(e_2,\dots,e_{2n}) = (\alpha^n)(e_1,\dots,e_{2n}) = 0 $$

showing that $\alpha^n = 0$.